# Storing duplicate content in git is an anti-pattern?

Tags: git

I have a monorepo with multiple apps with many similar or even identical files (think HTML themes: css, html, js, images, fonts). For each app these similar files can mildly drift apart in the future, but around 80% will stay the same for a long period of time.

Because of how git works internally it seems it will not duplicate the information if the files are the same, see below the **Details**.

So I am thinking of just storing all the copies in an easy to manage monorepo and avoid managing many repos, branches, dependencies, complicated build scripts, etc. Do you see any issue with this approach ? Store the same files in different directories in one git repo?

## Details

About git as an object store, see https://medium.com/@imjacobclark/a-quick-look-at-the-git-object-store-36f82f3babf7 for a simple introduction.

Git docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects (as axiac suggested)

We create a git repo with the first file:

```sh
user@host /tmp()$ mkdir gitrepo
user@host /tmp()$ cd gitrepo/
user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/gitrepo/.git/
user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ mkdir dir1
user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ echo "blabla" > dir1/file.tst

user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ git add .
user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ git config user.email "you@example.com"
user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ git config user.name "Your Name"
user@host /tmp/gitrepo()$ git commit -m "added file.txt in dir1"
[master (root-commit) 4d94965] added file.txt in dir1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 dir1/file.tst
```

The content of our file `file.tst` is hashed:

```sh
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ echo "blabla" | git hash-object --stdin -w
d35e62fcf6d62331a2cd9ccc43ff200254959420
```

If we look in the repo:

```sh
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ tree .git
.git
├── COMMIT_EDITMSG
├── HEAD
├── branches
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── pre-receive.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── index
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── logs
│   ├── HEAD
│   └── refs
│       └── heads
│           └── master
├── objects
│   ├── 1f
│   │   └── e738422124b7d61e6e67f17a6f3708cbea3ed4
│   ├── 4d
│   │   └── 94965ce499b156ddc381e3381777e3cfb47a5e
│   ├── ba
│   │   └── d334532dd229760d9108bd6541f7ccc9d73eb7
│   ├── d3
│   │   └── 5e62fcf6d62331a2cd9ccc43ff200254959420
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    │   └── master
    └── tags

16 directories, 24 files
```

So `file.tst` is here:

```sh
│   ├── d3
│   │   └── 5e62fcf6d62331a2cd9ccc43ff200254959420
```

Let's add the file in a different directory:

```sh
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ mkdir dir2
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ echo "blabla" > dir2/file.tst
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ git add .
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ git commit -m "added file.txt in dir2"
[master 6863b1f] added file.txt in dir2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 dir2/file.tst
```

We can see that git does not store `file.tst` twice:

```
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ sdiff tree1.txt tree2.txt
.git                                                          | .git/
├ COMMIT_EDITMSG                                                ├ COMMIT_EDITMSG
├ HEAD                                                          ├ HEAD
├ branches                                                      ├ branches
├ config                                                        ├ config
├ description                                                   ├ description
├ hooks                                                         ├ hooks
│   ├ applypatch-msg.sample                                     │   ├ applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├ commit-msg.sample                                         │   ├ commit-msg.sample
│   ├ fsmonitor-watchman.sample                                 │   ├ fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│   ├ post-update.sample                                        │   ├ post-update.sample
│   ├ pre-applypatch.sample                                     │   ├ pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├ pre-commit.sample                                         │   ├ pre-commit.sample
│   ├ pre-push.sample                                           │   ├ pre-push.sample
│   ├ pre-rebase.sample                                         │   ├ pre-rebase.sample
│   ├ pre-receive.sample                                        │   ├ pre-receive.sample
│   ├ prepare-commit-msg.sample                                 │   ├ prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   └ update.sample                                             │   └ update.sample
├ index                                                         ├ index
├ info                                                          ├ info
│   └ exclude                                                   │   └ exclude
├ logs                                                          ├ logs
│   ├ HEAD                                                      │   ├ HEAD
│   └ refs                                                      │   └ refs
│       └ heads                                                 │       └ heads
│           └ master                                            │           └ master
├ objects                                                       ├ objects
│   ├ 1f                                                        │   ├ 1f
│   │   └ e738422124b7d61e6e67f17a6f3708cbea3ed4                │   │   └ e738422124b7d61e6e67f17a6f3708cbea3ed4
│   ├ 4d                                                        │   ├ 4d
│   │   └ 94965ce499b156ddc381e3381777e3cfb47a5e                │   │   └ 94965ce499b156ddc381e3381777e3cfb47a5e
                                                              > │   ├ 68
                                                              > │   │   └ 63b1f211c6477669b7050c7dbd40c69e338d9a
                                                              > │   ├ 99
                                                              > │   │   └ ec1165c2ca0081084097e7240fa4418da8c4b2
│   ├ ba                                                        │   ├ ba
│   │   └ d334532dd229760d9108bd6541f7ccc9d73eb7                │   │   └ d334532dd229760d9108bd6541f7ccc9d73eb7
│   ├ d3                                                        │   ├ d3
│   │   └ 5e62fcf6d62331a2cd9ccc43ff200254959420                │   │   └ 5e62fcf6d62331a2cd9ccc43ff200254959420
│   ├ info                                                      │   ├ info
│   └ pack                                                      │   └ pack
└ refs                                                          └ refs
    ├ heads                                                         ├ heads
    │   └ master                                                    │   └ master
    └ tags                                                          └ tags

16 directories, 24 files                                      | 18 directories, 26 files
```

Git has stored two additional things, the commit message and the tree:

````
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ git cat-file 6863b1f211c6477669b7050c7dbd40c69e338d9a -p
tree 99ec1165c2ca0081084097e7240fa4418da8c4b2
parent 4d94965ce499b156ddc381e3381777e3cfb47a5e
author Your Name <you@example.com> 1574931936 +0200
committer Your Name <you@example.com> 1574931936 +0200

added file.txt in dir2
user@host /tmp/gitrepo(master)$ git cat-file 99ec1165c2ca0081084097e7240fa4418da8c4b2 -p
040000 tree bad334532dd229760d9108bd6541f7ccc9d73eb7    dir1
040000 tree bad334532dd229760d9108bd6541f7ccc9d73eb7    dir2
```bash
````

Comment: The technical details about how Git stores its data internally are not needed. They only make more difficult to understand what exactly do you ask. You can replace them with a link to a page that explains the internals of Git (f.e. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) to let the reader focus on your actual question.

Comment: Hi @axiac, tnks for the comment, adding your link to the official docs too. I've put details at the end specifically so that people can skip them, the full question is in the beginning. For me git obj store was a quick and interesting read, it may help readers of the question in the future...IMHO details should stay.